# Why DNS uses UDP as the transport layer protocol?

Tags: tcp, dns, udp, protocols

Why DNS uses UDP as the transport layer protocol?

Comment: Most queries fit into one message. You can re-send the message if you don’t get an answer. Less overhead than TCP.

Answer (score 24):

- UDP is much faster. TCP is slow as it requires 3 way handshake. The load on DNS servers is also an important factor. DNS servers (since they use UDP) don’t have to keep connections.
- DNS requests are generally very small and fit well within UDP segments.
- UDP is not reliable, but reliability can be added on application layer. An application can use UDP and can be reliable by using timeout and resend at application layer.

Answer reproduced from [1] under the [CCBY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/) license.

1. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/why-does-dns-use-udp-and-not-tcp/

Comment: 3 notes to your answer: 1) `DNS` uses **not** only `UDP` - sometimes it uses `TCP`, too. 2) The slowness of `TCP` lies mainly **not** in the connection establishment (which in turn is **not** only the 3-way handshake). 3) Reliability can be added on higher layers but it is **not** the case of DNS.

Comment: how dns can use tcp. please explain @MarianD ??? As the response time will increase

Comment: @AmanGupta, see the last two paragraphs in my answer, please.

Comment: This answer has been plagiarised, typos included, here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/why-does-dns-use-udp-and-not-tcp/

Comment: Yes I got it from another source, whether it was I don't remember. I could have named it.

Answer (score 11):

`UDP` is cheap. `UDP` itself is not reliable, but higher level protocols — as DNS — may maintain reliability, e.g. by repeating the `UDP` datagram in the case of no response.

But the last is not the case for `DNS`. `DNS` itself uses sometimes besides `UDP` (as its primary protocol) the reliable *Transmission Control Protocol* (`TCP`), too.

The last is used when the response data size exceeds `512` bytes, and for tasks which require the reliable delivery (e.g. *zone transfers*).

Moreover, there are some resolver implementations that use `TCP` for *all* queries.